# Execute Test-NetConnection continuously until key pressed in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I would like to execute below command continuously until a key is pressed. As an example:

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName google.com -Port 80
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `do{...}until()` with `[console]::KeyAvailable`

```
do
{
    test-Connection -ComputerName google.com -Count 1
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
until([Console]::KeyAvailable)
```

Comment: but how to specify the port 42424? I need to specify it and parameter -TcpPort does not work. Using its successor cmdlet, TestNet-Connection I can specify a port using -Port parameter. How could I do this using TestNet-Connection cmdlet instead?

Comment: I'm not sure what that has to do with the question you asked about. Perhaps you can find an existing question/answer on that topic, otherwise create a new question about it.

Comment: Well, in the post I detailed to perfom a TestNet-Connection cmdlet on a machine and port.